# Issues Calculating Average Acceleration?

Tags: physics

So I'm doing a Physics problem here and I'm down to my last answer and I honestly can't figure out where I'm going wrong. The problem is as follows:

> From t = 0 to t = 4.22 min, a man stands still, and from t = 4.22 min
>   to t = 8.44 min, he walks briskly in a straight line at a constant
>   speed of 1.06 m/s. What is his average acceleration in the time interval 1.00 min to 5.22 min? What is his average acceleration in the time interval 2.00 min to 6.22 min?

It's my understanding that average acceleration is the change in velocity over the change in time which would lead to this calculation, correct?

$\frac{1.06 m/s}{253.2s}$ which gives the result of $0.004 m/s^2$ but this answer is apparently incorrect. Am I missing a step somewhere? Or do I just not understand average acceleration?

Comment: Your logic and such seems to be spot on.  Given that you say you found "this answer is apparently incorrect", I assume you are submitting it on an online homework site with answer verification.  I expect with that in mind, that it may be looking for proper significant figures (all numbers appearing are 3 sig-figs long, so have your answer 3 sig-figs as well, .00419).  Alternatively, perhaps it wants it written in a specific format or with different units.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah, that's probably what's throwing me, thank you! I forgot all about significant figures heh.